# Cannot connect HTTPS by docker, traefik , SSL

Tags: docker, traefik

i've some issues with traefik when i use TLS to connect my API, it cannot connect, i've config follow traefik document https://traefik.io/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/, someone can help me

version: "3.8"

services:

myproject:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/test/myproject:latest

env_file:
  - ./myproject/.env

restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  - ./myproject/jwt.pem:/config/jwt.pem
  - ./myproject/jwt.pub:/config/jwt.pub
logging:
  driver: json-file
  options:
    max-size: 200k
    max-file: "10"
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.http.routers.myproject.rule=Host(`mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
  - traefik.http.routers.myproject.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.myproject.entrypoints=web,websecure
  - traefik.http.services.myproject.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
  - traefik.http.middlewares.my_headers.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT,POST,DELETE
  - traefik.http.middlewares.my_headers.headers.accesscontrolalloworigin=*
  - traefik.http.middlewares.my_headers.headers.accessControlAllowHeaders=*
  - traefik.http.middlewares.my_headers.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100
  - traefik.http.middlewares.my_headers.headers.addvaryheader=true
  - traefik.http.middlewares.api_v1_strippath.stripprefix.prefixes=/api
  - traefik.http.routers.myproject.middlewares=my_headers,api_v1_strippath
```

traefik:

```
image: "traefik:v2.2"

container_name: "traefik"

command:
  - "--api.insecure=true"
  - "--providers.file.directory=/configuration/"
  - "--providers.file.watch=true"
  - "--providers.docker=true"
  - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
  - 8080:8080
volumes:
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  - "./home/ec2-user/myproject/traefik/configuration/:/configuration/"
```

and certificates.toml :

[[tls.certificates]]

```
certFile = "/configuration/mykey.cert"
keyFile = "/configuration/mykey.key"
```

Comment: Where is the toml file located?

Comment: Hi Blake, toml file in /home/ec2-user/myproject/traefik/configuration/certificates.toml

Comment: Okay yeah that seems reasonable. I noticed on the blog, they seem to be putting it somewhere that didn't make sense ("files/.."). What sort of errors are you getting when you try to run docker compose, if any?